# Delete record by object from QueryBuilder

Tags: excel, vba

as ***delete*** function does not work in Query Builder (BI), if there is possibile to delete record from Query Builder by VBA ?
I have an object:

***Set example_Object = objInfoStore.Query("select * from ci_infoobjects where si_id = " & si_id_number)***

In that object is one record.
What should I do with ***example_Object*** to remove his content from database.
I will appreciate for any help.

Regards
Marek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
Set objInfoObject = example_Object.Item(1)
objInfoObject.DeleteNow
```